# Memory Leaks tutorial in iphone

Tags: iphone, xcode, memory-leaks, memory-leak-detector

is there is any good tutorial link that can help me in the memory leaks of iphone,, b/c I am facing some problem whenever I allocate a memeory , in the dealloc I am releasing that memeory, but the problem is that when I run application in the (Run-> Run With Performance Tools -> Leaks) but I got the leaks through there.. how can I resolve it...

reply me plz

Comment: I don't remember the name exactly, there was one session in WWDC 2010. You can get the video on Apple's developer portal.

Comment: http://developer.apple.com/videos/wwdc/2010/ Watch the "Session 311 - Advanced Memory Analysis with Instruments"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In XCode, you can run `Build and Analyze`. XCode shows memory leaks with arrows of you bad memory management.

This is a good tutorial : [iphone-memory-management-tips](http://akosma.com/2009/01/28/10-iphone-memory-management-tips/)

Comment: how can I resolve it... whenever I run the application and the variable are dealloc and after that when I run app again, it will show me again that memeory leaks? how can I resolve it